# What do the tomatoes on the prize wheel do?

Tags: grindstone

The Carnival of Creeps update added tickets you can use to spin a prize wheel. Most of the prizes are normal crafting materials, but then there are the two tomato spaces.

What do the tomato spaces on the prize wheel do?

[image: prize wheel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tomatoes are dud spaces. They don't do anything other than splatter tomatoes on your screen.